# Why won't my 96 Honda Civic Coupe start

Tags: starting

I was driving my 96 Civic when the battery arced out and blew the main ECU fuse under the hood I replaced the fuse and now everytime I turn the ignition on the running lights turn on won't turn off until I disconnect the battery and it blows the fuse again I checked the main ECU itself and the relays and it's neither of them

Comment: There's a short circuit somewhere in the car's wiring. Since car wiring (even wiring in a 20 year-old car) is complicated and looks like a map of the New York City subway system, you'll need (or must find someone with) troubleshooting skills to find the fault and rectify it.

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought something fuse together when the battery are gout I was just hoping I was wrong I guess but its a good thing I know what I'm doing I just didn't want to do that cuz its about to really suck thank you